# How to use jQuery validation plugin in input with different name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I work with different name in input !!!
after click submit in form show error in all `<label for="passenger"></label>`

How do I separate?

For example: You've selected three rooms of a hotel.

`lenHotel = 3;` number is changed.

add script:

```
<script src="../lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

`script` is:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= lenHotel; i++) {
  $("#Step-02").find('#information-box').append(
    "<div class='box-content'>" +
    "<div class='field-row clearfix'>" +
        "<label for='passenger'></label> " +
        "<input id='passenger' name='passenger_" + i +"' required type='text'> " +
    "</div>" +
    "<div class='field-row clearfix'> " +
        "<div class='col-xs-6'> " +
            "<select id='country' name='country_" + i + "'> "+
                "<option value='1'>Country name</option>" +
                "<option value='2'>Country Name</option>" +
            "</select>" +
        "</div>" +
    "</div>" +
  "</div>"
 ); 
}
```

After print, HTML is:

```
<div class="box-content">
<div class="field-row clearfix">
    <label for="passenger"></label> 
    <input id="passenger" name="passenger_1" required="" type="text">
</div>
<div class="field-row clearfix">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <select id="p-status" name="country_1">
            <option value="1">Country name</option>
            <option value="2">Country name</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="box-content">
<div class="field-row clearfix">
    <label for="passenger"></label> 
    <input id="passenger" name="passenger_2" required="" type="text">
</div>
<div class="field-row clearfix">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <select id="p-status" name="country_2">
            <option value="1">Country name</option>
            <option value="2">Country name</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="box-content">
<div class="field-row clearfix">
    <label for="passenger"></label> 
    <input id="passenger" name="passenger_3" required="" type="text">
</div>
<div class="field-row clearfix">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <select id="p-status" name="country_3">
            <option value="1">Country name</option>
            <option value="2">Country name</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

This validate function:

```
$().ready(function() {
// validate the form when it is submitted
var validator = $("#form_sample_1").validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        // Append error within linked label
        $(element).closest("form").find("label[for='" +
            element.attr("id") + "']").append(error);
        console.log(error);
    },
    errorElement: "span",
    messages: {
        passenger: {
            required: "Required",
            minlength: "Your passenger name must be at least 5 characters"
        }
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Are you asking how you separate elements with the same ID or name? Easy, you use a different name for each element, as you can't use the same name/ID for multiple elements

Comment: @adeneo Thank you so much, If you selected 10 rooms of a hotel. What should we do now?

Comment: actually, you can use the same **name**, and **must** do so for radio buttons if you want them to work properly

Comment: @JaromandaX, Thank you so mush, But my problem is in different message...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you are generalising here and you are using same `id` for multiple elements:

```
$(element).closest("form").find("label[for='" + element.attr("id") + "']").append(error);
```

So you need to change it to something that is relative to that element. Also, it looks like you are duplicating the `id`, which is a crime.

Change your `id` for the `passenger`s to `passenger_1`, `passenger_2`... and so on and it should work.

```
"<div class='field-row clearfix'>" +
    "<label for='passenger_" + i +"'></label> " +
    "<input id='passenger_" + i +"' name='passenger_" + i +"' required type='text'> " +
"</div>" +
```

Comment: Thank you so much, But how i do show different message  in jQuery validate?

Comment: @Shayvard `messages: {
        passenger: {` Here, change `passenger` to `passenger_1` blah blah.

Comment: If you selected 10 rooms of a hotel. What should we do now?